# How to fix 'incorrect artifact/model path on HDFS showing on MLflow server'

Tags: mlflow

I run a mlflow server with the following command using mlflow, version 1.2.0

```
mlflow server --host myhost -p myport --backend-store-uri mysql://user@localhost/mlflow --default-artifact-root hdfs://myhost/user/myid/mlflow_test
```

I run the experiment from MLflow tutorial quickstart https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html

the command:

```
mlflow run sklearn_elasticnet_wine -P alpha=0.5 --no-conda
```

the code to log the model is

```
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")
```

in

```
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine/train.py
```

I visit the server by webbrowser myhost: myport and check the run I ran.

I successfully get the ran info by myhost: `myport/#/experiments/0/runs/run_id`

in this page, i found that the first layer (model directory) path is correct. that is, `run_id/artifacts/model`
[correct path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJZWv.png)

but once I click the MLmodel file under model folder, the path get wrong:
I expect to see        `run_id/artifacts/model/MLmodel`
but actually it was    `run_id/artifacts/MLmodel`
[wrong path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIhVR.png)